# Web3.js enabled mobile browsers and wallets

Tags: web3js, mobile-wallet

What mobile browsers or wallets there exist with proper web3.js support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Status.im](https://status.im/) (see [FAQ](https://wiki.status.im/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_interact_with_web3_object.3F) for more details)
- [Coinbase Wallet](https://www.toshi.org/) (see [docs](https://developers.toshi.org/docs/webview-dapps#section-web3js-enabled-browser) for more details)
- [Cipher](https://www.cipherbrowser.com/)
- [Trust Wallet](https://trustwallet.com/dapp)

Comment: https://trustwalletapp.com/

Comment: Opera Mobile Browser?